# Azure web app user managment the east way

Tags: azure, authentication

If I develop an application, for example a website where users should be able to login to use the app. This could be an online casino. The users have to be able to sign up and sign in. What is the best way to do the authentication in Azure? It should be a basic login and register page on the website. Ideal would be to use a username and password basic authentication but I don't want to develop it myself, I want to use Azure.

Comment: There's really no way to answer this objectively; there are several approaches, and services, available to you. But tool/product/service recommendation questions are off-topic, as are opinion-solicitation questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "easiest" / 'best" way is relative. I believe you're looking for Azure AD B2C, which basically will handle the registering process for you and store users into your Azure AD.

Follow the 3 steps from Azure Docs:

1-Create an Azure Active Directory B2C tenant

2-Register a web application in Azure Active Directory B2C

3-Create user flows and custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant

Comment: Best not to answer such opinion-soliciting questions. The question, as written, is off-topic. The OP has shown no code or specific issue, and there's just no way to answer this objectively. (note: this can also be seen as a product/service recommendation, another reason for it being off-topic)